# An Extra Drive is Showing in My Computer but not in Disk Management in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-desktop

Hey Any one please help me !! An unknown extra drive is shown in My Computer and when i tried to open it ... it says Access Denied .... I don't know from where it come from and when i checked it in Disk Management its not their. Please help me to remove that drive.

Below is the screen short of that Drive & Disk Management.[image: Drive name is Z]

[image: This is when i tried to Access the Drive]

[image: ACCESS DENIED]

[image: Screen Short Of DISK MANAGEMENT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I restarted my Windows system it's gone.
Remember: You should do a restart, not a shut down.

I think it's related to Windows updates.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this could be that 100MB Windows Reserved EFI system partition that you somehow started displaying instead of it being hidden by default.